# Convert tab-delimited raw data stored as text string into Hive table?

Tags: mysql, hadoop, hive, hiveql

I have tab-delimited raw data that I have stored as a text string in a Hive table. I would like to be able to grab the first, third, ... , x fields, and store the results into another table with field names of my choosing. For example, given the following:

`raw_table`:

```
Field1  Field2  Field3
01001   1       00-00-32-0-700-000.000
```

new `custID_pin` Hive table:

```
custID  PIN
 01001  00-00-32-0-700-000.000
```

Here's what I have so far:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS custID_pin;
CREATE TABLE custID_pin AS
SELECT 
[psuedocode: column1, column3, where columns are defined by the tab delimiter]
FROM raw_table;
```

How do I write the select statement to achieve the desired results mentioned above, in the case of a tab-delimited rather than fixed-width file.

Answer (score 0):

something like this?

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS custID_pin;
CREATE TABLE custID_pin row format delimited fields terminated by '\t' STORED AS TEXTFILE AS select column1, column3 from raw_table where columns1="value";
```